# "ERROR: Validation error" message when executing two Sequelize commands in "pretest" script

Tags: node.js, postgresql, testing, sequelize.js

I'm writing tests for my project. It uses Sequelize and I thought about doing the following:

```
"pretest": "NODE_ENV=testing yarn sequelize db:migrate && yarn sequelize db:seed:all",
"test": "mocha --require @babel/register 'src/tests/**/*.spec.js'",
"posttest": "NODE_ENV=testing yarn sequelize db:migrate:undo:all"
```

But the following shows:

```
❯ yarn test     
yarn run v1.19.2
$ NODE_ENV=testing yarn sequelize db:migrate && yarn sequelize db:seed:all
$ /home/gabriel/Workspace/graphql-apollo/node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.13.1, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.2]

Loaded configuration file "src/config/database.js".
== 20191123132531-create-users: migrating =======
== 20191123132531-create-users: migrated (0.047s)

== 20191123132658-create-messages: migrating =======
== 20191123132658-create-messages: migrated (0.028s)

$ /home/gabriel/Workspace/graphql-apollo/node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:seed:all

Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.13.1, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.2]

Loaded configuration file "src/config/database.js".
== 20191123132945-users: migrating =======

ERROR: Validation error

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

If I execute the migration and seeding command separately, it works fine.  I also tried to use `concurrently`, but the same happens.

```
"pretest": "concurrently 'NODE_ENV=testing yarn sequelize db:migrate' 'yarn sequelize db:seed:all'",
```

Answer (score 7):

@gamofe Add the `--debug` flag to the command to see more info about the error. e.g.

```
    $ sequelize db:seed:all --debug
```

It's very likely you are getting this error because you are running `sequelize db:seed:all` without undoing previous seed. If your table already contains the data you are trying to seed in which some of them have unique constraint, you'll hit the unique constraint error.
To solve this you would need to run the `sequelize db:seed:undo:all` before seeding.
You can find more info here https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html

Comment: What to do if we want to automate the deploy and run the seed:all command to make sure that we update the data on the database? We would run it every time the deploy is made to the server.
If exists, it's is ignored, if not, it is added.
This happens when we run the db:migrate. It checks what is new in the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it as follows:

Wrong: "pretest": "NODE_ENV=test sequelize db:migrate && sequelize db:seed:all"

Right: "pretest": "NODE_ENV=test sequelize db:migrate && **NODE_ENV=test** sequelize db:seed:all"

Answer (score 0):

Check your `queryInterface.bulkInsert()` or other insert statements are passed `created_at` and `updated_at` values. The seed part of sequelize does not automatically add this in - and the database has a NOT NULL restriction on these fields.

In my case I had to change the content of my seed file to include the createdAt and updatedAt fields.

I changed:

```js
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [
      { id:1, name: `God`, type: UserTypes.Person },
    ]);
  }
}
```

to:

```js
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    const currentTime = new Date(new Date().toUTCString()).toISOString();
    await queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [
      { id:++i, name: `God`, type: UserTypes.Person, createdAt: currentTime, updatedAt: currentTime },
    ]);
  }
}
```

Note: I use the `underscored: true` option. If you don't you will need to use created_at and updated_at in place of createdAt and updatedAt.